# Extracting subset of a string using regex in linux

Tags: linux, grep

I have a simple list like following

```
ss_Asd_n1_455_9_1
ss_Asd_n1_98_9_32
ss_Asd_n1_562_9_145
ss_Asd_n1_1_9_6
```

Using regex linux I want the list to trimmed like follwing

```
ss_Asd_n1_455_9
ss_Asd_n1_98_9
ss_Asd_n1_562_9 
ss_Asd_n1_1_9
```

I tried the following code but it did not print any output

```
grep '[a-z_]*[a-zA-Z]+(\_)[v0-9]+(\_)[0-9]+(\_)[0-9]'
```

Kindly guide me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why `grep` if you need to modify the lines? Use `sed -i.bak 's/\(.*\)_[^_]*$/\1/' file`

Comment: Or `sed -i.bak 's/_[0-9]*$//' file`. Do you really need to check the format that thoroughly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you simply want `sed 's/_[^_]*$//' filename`

To edit the file in-place, use `sed -i` (or if you are on BSD / MacOS, `sed -i ''`).

Answer (score 0):

using grep I'd use the perl regex syntax 'P' and match only the matching portion 'o'

```
echo ss_Asd_n1_455_9_1 | grep -oP '[a-z]*_(?:[a-z]|[A-Z])+_[a-z][0-9]+_[0-9]+_[0-9]+'
ss_Asd_n1_455_9
```